How calculate $\chi(O_P)$, a skyscrapper sheaf?
I'm beggining with the calculation of cohomology groups in sheaf theory and I have a doubt about how to calculate some things. So I would like to ask for help if some step in this calculation are wrong or not.
Let $X$ be a $L-$scheme, where $L$ is a field, and $P$ a point of $X$. Let $O_P$ the structure sheaf of the point $P$. I want to know $\chi (O_P)$. I know that $O_P$ is flasque, so $H^i(X,O_P)=0$ for $i>0$, so $\chi(O_P)=dim_LH^0(X,O_P)$. But $H^0(X,O_P)$ is the global sections of $O_P$, so $H^0(X,O_P)=k(P)$, where $k(P)$ is the residue field of the point. Thus $\chi(O_P)=[k(P):L]$.
I would like to say that $\chi(O_P)=1$, but this means that $k(P)=L$, ie, $P$ is a $L-$point. Is   $P$ is a $L-$point necessary in order to get $\chi(O_P)=1$ or there are conditions on $P$ to get this or conditions over the field $L$? If so, which are such conditions? Maybe $\chi(O_P)=1$ for all $P \in X$? Do I misunderstandig something?
Thanks in advance!

I'm not sure what you're asking. You've already given a formula for $\chi(\mathcal{O}_P)$ and it disagrees with your second claim unless $L = k(P)$.
